# Change Pyttsx3's sound output source

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech

I am using a library called **pyttsx3** to convert text to speech. How can I direct the output sound to a specific speaker?

Code:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# -Select an output source-

engine.say('Hello World!')
engine.runAndWait()
```